# How to remove these faucet handles? Anyone recognize this faucet?

Tags: faucet, sink

no screw or hole visible all around the handle or stem.
no indentation below the round top to pop it out.
tried to gently use covered pliers to turn the round top counter-clockwise, but that's either stuck or not the right way.

sadly I don't know the manufacturer, no logo anywhere
[image: faucet]

[image: handle detail]

Comment: The silver top part was probably made to pop off, but there seems to be quite a bit of rust/dirt/gunk under it acting like glue.  Might need a thin old knife/s and tap(lightly, not with a sledge) them in around the base.

Comment: Pry a small screwdriver and try to pop off that silver cap on top

Comment: Try the silver cap first, if this doesn't budge or reveal a screw cap, it might be from inside (i.e. the base in the picture). You'd have to screw off the entire faucet first. What is the reason you're attempting to remove the handles?

Comment: Another vote for popping the silver cap off.   A little penetrating oil could help.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the culprit.

[image: cap]

The screw is under it.

The silver cap already has some dents in it, indicating it is hollow underneath it hiding the screw to remove the valve.

It is hard to see on your photo but look here if this is a opening to insert blade/screwdriver.

Many years of use, have accumulated dirt and calc.

Use vinegar to loosen the calc. Use blade and go around the cap slot, to loosen it. Insert small screwdriver or blade and pop it upwards.

Comment: When you say "calc" do you mean calcium? If so, it'd probably be best to spell it all the way out at least once to help reduce confusion, especially for folks who are new to DIY/home improvement.

Comment: @FreeMan accepted, and thank you for the vote of confirmation